# Confusion in work done in moving charge to infinity from center of conductor

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work, potential, capacitance

> A point charge $q$ is at center of spherical conducting shell of inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$. Find work done in moving charge to infinity.

The answer (given in book) is:

$$W = \frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)$$

This can be obtained easily by integrating energy density or by finding the difference in total potential energy of the system initially and finally.

However, I see that this value is identical to charging of a spherical capacitor. Hence it implies the charge was taken out bit by bit as in capacitor. Using:

$$W=-\int dqV$$

gives the same answer as above. The problem is, by this I come to the conclusion that this will be work done if the charge was broken down into infinite fragments and then moved out bit by bit.

Thus work done if we do not break the charge down to infinite fragments would be simply be $qV$ i.e.

$$\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)$$

Apparently this does not hold true if compare the potential energies of the system initially and finally and say that work is change in energy. What is wrong with my reasoning? What would it be if we do not break the charge to $dq$ and say that we wish to move it together? The two situations are quite different and I cannot justify that they should have same values. A short answer without any calculation is enough.

$V$ used here is potential at center:

$$V = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

UPDATE:
This is a question 2.60 from Introduction to Electrodyamics by Griffith.
I thought about it and now believe that the answer is certainly $$\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)$$ and not $$\frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)$$ as if we go by the solution in instructor's manual and find energy difference only, we miss the energy loss as heat in a capacitor. Taking that into account, we get
$$\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)$$
Am i correct here (as this is quite a famous book)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overthinking it - the author meant this to be an exercise in electrostatics, so no energy transformation into heat is allowed. He wants you to calculate electrostatic potential energy of such a system. The correct answer is

$$
\mathscr{E}_p = \frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)
$$
which is negative (the conductor attracts the inner charged particle). When the inner charged particle is removed and put far away, the electrostatic potential energy of the system is zero. So the minimum work needed to take the inner charge out and far away, in ideal case, is minus the above value.

Of course, in reality, the work can be much higher, due to losses into heat or radiation - but this is meant to be ignored in the original question.